# Qt translate escape sequence

Tags: c++, qt, escaping

I have:

```
    &#186;C
```

I want to translate this for display into ºC

I'm using Qt 5.6, is there a built in function I can call to translate this sequence?

Qt has functions to translate the symbol to an escape sequence:

```
    QString QString::toHtmlEscaped()
```

But what I need is the corresponding function to translate back to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QTextDocument` or `QTextDocumentFragment` to decode html entities:

```
QString html_string = "&#186;C";
QString plain_string = QTextDocumentFragment::fromHtml(b).toPlainText();
```

Answer (score 1):

For my project in order to display a temperature i did:

```
    QChar degreesSymbol(0260);
    QString stringToShow = "Your number " + degreesSymbol + "C";
```

Comment: Thank you, however this doesn't answer question, I need to translate html escape codes into the actual character.

Answer (score 1):

You may use C++ regexp-s, below is sample code.

as a side note: you can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol that degree sign is

```
U+00B0 ° DEGREE SIGN (HTML &#176; · &deg;).
```

`&#186` is for:

```
U+00BA º MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR (HTML &#186; · &ordm;) (superscript letter used in abbreviating words; varies with the font and sometimes underlined)
```

[[live]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RUebBZGcnTQX9LXS)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

std::string html_unescape_char(int html_escape_code) {
    switch (html_escape_code) {
        case 176:
        return "\u00B0"; // °       
        case 186:
        return "\u00BA"; // º        
        // todo: use std::mbtowc or add other entities (ie. from http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

    }
    return "?";
}

std::string html_unescape_string(std::string s) {
    std::regex r(R"((.*?)&#(\d+);)");
    std::ostringstream res;        
    for(std::sregex_iterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), r), end_it; it != end_it; ++it) {        
        res << it->format("$1");
        int html_escape_code = std::stoi((*it)[2]); // !! stoi might throw
        res << html_unescape_char(html_escape_code);
    }
    return res.str();
}

void test(std::string s) {
    std::cout << " in:" << s << "\n" << "out:" << html_unescape_string(s) << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    test("&#186;C");
    test("123&#186;C not the same as 123&#176;C");
    test("&#186;C  123&#186;C    1&#186;C");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the degree symbol was an example, isn't there an opposite function to 'toHtmlEscaped' that returns a QString with content translated?

Comment: @SPlatten I am not aware of such function